# Using ModelBuilder of ArcGIS Pro to export Python to build REST service without using ArcGIS Server

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, modelbuilder, rest-service

I made a model using ModelBuilder in ArcGIS Pro and I exported it as a Python file. My model use a Digital Elevation Model and some layers like Forests, Rivers, Lakes. In the end, I get some areas where a helicopter can land without intersecting with forests, lakes, rivers. Now, I want to do a rest service where someone can say what area they need and get those places where a helicopter can land. I want to use this script.

How could I do that?

I don't have a license for ArcGIS Server.

Comment: Hi welcome to GIS SE! Please take the [tour] to learn all about this website. To get the best possible help, I advise you to [edit] your question to include what the outputs are of your model builder script and what you want to do in the REST API

Comment: I think your Esri License Agreement prevents you from creating a REST service that calls ArcPy functions in your Python script.

Comment: Thanks. I thought it would be possible.